# Wordpress Vagrant VV - How to setup git?

Tags: wordpress, git, vagrant, vagrant-plugin

I am using Varying-Vagrant-Vagrants for Wordpress development. I am able to setup a new site, it works great when I run `vv create`. However how can I setup git into my `wp-content` directory?

I've already ran the command `git init` on `wp-content` directory and after adding all files, I ran `git commit -m "Initial commit"` and got this error message:

```
gpg: skipped "username <username@emails.com>": secret key not available
gpg: signing failed: secret key not available
error: gpg failed to sign the data
fatal: failed to write commit object
```

(I removed my personal details from the message)

Any idea what this error is about? I can run git normally on other projects that are not part of Wordpress VVV.

Comment: How does your global gitconfig file look like?

Comment: user.email={{**myEmailAddress**}}. Git works fine on other applicaitons that are not part of Wordpress VVV. Is there any particular key on gitconfig that I should look?

Answer (score 0):

you need a `user.name` on top of your email. (probably your name is set in your gitconfig on your host machine or the other VM). In v-v-v VM you can run

```
git config --global user.name "<name>"
```

to add your name automatically or edit the gitconfig file